# Floating button needs to be hided above keyboard

Tags: android

I have a custom floating button.It works fine.I have some editText field too.My problem is whenever I am entering text the floating button appears above the keyboard.How to hide it? i.e.: Floating button should not visible when I am entering text.

**My Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.te.thm.se.Insert"
    android:background="@drawable/primary_gradient">
    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:indicatorName="BallScaleMultipleIndicator"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:indicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/header_card"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/requisition_no"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/requisition_no_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/requisition_no_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/autogenerated"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/title_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/date_label"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="00-00-0000"
            android:id="@+id/date_value"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="getDates"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/company_name_label"
            android:id="@+id/company_name"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>


        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:id="@+id/company_name_value"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <!--<Spinner-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/company_name_value"/>-->
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/employee_name_label"
                    android:id="@+id/Employee_name"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>

                <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/employee_name_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <!--<Spinner-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/employee_name_value"/>-->
            </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/requisition_status_label"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/status"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/open"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/status_value"/>
        </LinearLayout>
            <com.unstoppable.submitbuttonview.SubmitButton
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:id="@+id/approve_button"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:onClick="submitRequisition"
                app:buttonColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:buttonText="Submit"
                app:buttonTextSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/requisition_detail_list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <com.robertlevonyan.views.customfloatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/custom_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabType="roundedSquare"
        app:fabText="SAVE"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </com.robertlevonyan.views.customfloatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

But It will also hide editText field

Comment: Use **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`**

Comment: @NileshRathod It will hide the floating button...But it not showing the text entering filed also

Comment: share you whole layout with Question

Comment: @NileshRathod bro added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have gone one library with which you can find the visibility of
>   Keyboard. and i have handle the visibility of floating action button
>   when keyboard is visible or not.
>
> add dependency in app.gradle file

implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'

> Add following code in Activity onCreateMethod()

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
                this,
                new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                       if(isOpen)
                       {
                           custom_fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           custom_fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it false. Something like this

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
```

Comment: bro then the button will appear at screen centre..I want it to be at bottom centre,but invisibe when keyboard appears

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity of Android.manifest file

`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`
to
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

and put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Comment: bro still it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Remove gravity from FloatingActionButton

```
<com.robertlevonyan.views.customfloatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/custom_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabType="roundedSquare"
        app:fabText="SAVE"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    </com.robertlevonyan.views.customfloatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```